# Passing Object and all of its values between forms

Tags: c#, forms, oop, object, parameter-passing

How do I pass an object and all of its values from Form A to form B?

Below is some 'hypothetical code' that I have produced where I search though a list in order to polymorphically book an Act. Once the name is found I then calculate the price based on hours booked. All of this is done using the object 's'.  All of this code is on a button on Form A.

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string searchName = Convert.ToString(lstActs.SelectedItem);
    foreach (Singer s in singers)
    {
        if (String.Compare(searchName, s.Name) == 0)
        {
            s.HoursBooked = Convert.ToInt32(nudHours.Value);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(s.HoursBooked), s.Name);
            double price = s.CalculatePrice(s.Price, s.HoursBooked);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(price));
        }
    }


    Confirm myNewForm = new Confirm();
    myNewForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new class with the data you want to display:

```
public class ConfirmationData
{
    // some properties
}
```

Fill the object:

```
ConfirmationData data = new ConfirmationData();

string searchName = Convert.ToString(lstActs.SelectedItem);
foreach (Singer s in singers)
{
    if (String.Compare(searchName, s.Name) == 0)
    {
        s.HoursBooked = Convert.ToInt32(nudHours.Value);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(s.HoursBooked), s.Name);
        double price = s.CalculatePrice(s.Price, s.HoursBooked);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(price));

        .... fill 'data' with the Information you want to display
    }
}
```

Finally pass the data to the Confirm Dialog and show it:

```
Confirm myNewForm = new Confirm(data);
myNewForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that I make a new class called confirmation data? Just because I have a Form called 'Confirm' and that is what I need the object and all of it's data passing to. At the bottom I am just switching between forms. Thanks for your time!

Comment: "confirmation data" is just a transport object. And yes, a new class. Because the data (singer) you want to pass to the Confirm view is not accesible at the bottom, you need to use another object. You could also pass a list of singers (List<Singer>) as transport object.

Comment: hey man, I added a new class as you said, I then passed the data as a parameter to the new form and added another constructor to that form to receive the data  

private DataTransfer data;

public Confirm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

public Confirm(DataTransfer data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

And I am now getting the error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'DataTransfer' is less accessible than method 'Confirm.Confirm(DataTransfer)'... Any ideas, thank you!

Comment: Mark the class 'DataTransfer' as public.

Comment: You, my friend are a life saver. Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear for you. If it helped, you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your Confirm class` work depends on the value of Singer class, doesnt it? If so, you can add a parameter to the Confirm constructor, like that:

```
public Confirm(Singer singer)
{
    //null-check I suppose
}
```

So the button press handler you wrote would end like this:

```
Confirm myNewForm = new Confirm(s);//where s is Singer
    myNewForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();
```

Otherwise, you can add a new public property to Confirm class and assign a value to it before showing the dialog:

```
Confirm myNewForm = new Confirm();
myNewForm.Singer = s;
    myNewForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I have tried these and for some reason I cant access the object 's' or any of its data on the new form. I have tried overloading the constructor as well but can't seem to access the object :/